# if condition not working in python comparing float

Tags: python, django, if-statement

If condition in my code is not working properly.
Here's my code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ask =request.POST['ask']
    model_directory ="dialog/rasa/models/model_20170831-105056"

    metadata = Metadata.load(model_directory)   # where model_directory points to the folder the model is persisted in
    interpreter = Interpreter.load(metadata, RasaNLUConfig("dialog/rasa/config_mitie_sklearn.json"))
    r=interpreter.parse(ask)
    # r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/parse', params={'q':ask})
    # r = r.json()

    intent = r['intent']['name']
    text = r['text']
    confidence = r['intent']['confidence']
    confidence = float(confidence)
    confidence = round(confidence,2)
    #confidence =type(confidence)


    if r['entities']:
        entity =r['entities'][0]['entity']
        value =r['entities'][0]['value']
        query=Dialog.objects.raw('SELECT 1 id,dialog FROM test WHERE intent=%s AND entity=%s AND value=%s', [intent,entity,value])
    else:
        query=Dialog.objects.raw('SELECT 1 id,dialog FROM test WHERE intent=%s', [intent])

    for x in query:
        dialog = ""

        if confidence < 0.50:
            dialog = "Sorry"
            # result = {"conversation": {"text":text,"intent": intent,"confidence":confidence,"entity":entity,"value":value,"output": dialog,"context": "null"}}
            # result = json.dumps(result,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        else:
            dialog = "ok"
            #dialog=unidecode.unidecode(x.dialog)
            # result = {"conversation": {"text":text,"intent": intent,"confidence":confidence,"entity":entity,"value":value,"output": dialog,"context": "null"}}
            # result = json.dumps(result,sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    return HttpResponse(dialog)
```

Only else part is working. When confidence is less than 0.50

```
"local variable 'dialog' referenced before assignment error"
```

comes. Confidence type is `numpy.float64`. I am using python 2.7.

Comment: please, show full code

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. There might be an issue with the indentation. Please post your whole view.

Comment: That sounds like `confidence` doesn't have a value assigned to it by the time you're trying to compare it to 0.5.

Comment: @orangeInk That would raise an error regarding `confidence`, not `dialog`.

Comment: @Selcuk Indentation is unlikely a problem .i think problem is comparing with float .

Comment: try to print(confidence) and check what it  returns

Comment: it returns 0.44

Comment: Please post the _complete_ error message.

Comment: "local variable 'dialog' referenced before assignment error" if confidence is less than 0.50

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got `dialog == "ok"` or something? (note the double `=`)

Answer (score 1):

if query is null, the dialog is not defined.

fixed as blew

```
dialog = "ok"
for x in query:
    if confidence < 0.50:
        dialog = "Sorry"
```

Comment: this is just a workaround.now it prints ok but the problem with condition still exists

Answer (score -1):

This is a normal Python behavior.  Dialog is not being defined before your `if` block. Even if you got a `else` statement, Python still thinks it could be displaying something not being defined anywhere. For instance, what if your `if` condition cannot be evaluated to True or False?

Define dialog somewhere before your if block and everything should be fine, without changing anything to what you are trying to do!

Comment: defined dialog before if statement still not working

Comment: "What if your if condition cannot be evaluated to True or False?" - How is THAT possible?

Comment: For instance, if confidence does not exist it will raise an exception, though condition will never be evaluated (evaluation will stop when exception is raised).

Comment: But anyway, Bear Brown answer shows that it should still work if confidence is being defined correctly before the `if` block. I thought it would have raised an error or at least a warning. Still, I think it is a bad practice to use somewhere else a variable that has been defined really locally, without trying to catch any exception.